How to correctly and simply display multiline string literal in Jupyter Notebook?
I am looking for a solution that is the most convenient for casual, exploratory notebook use.
I have several functions that output strings with multiple lines. When this appears in the output cell of a Jupyter notebook, it is formatted without multiple lines, just the '\n' characters. I can force the string to format in the output by wrapping the function in a "print" but I would like to avoid that inconvenience.
Suggestions? I am open to a setting I must apply to the whole notebook or in an initial cell.

Versions
python                    3.11.8
ipython                   8.15.0
jupyter lab               4.0.8

This code block placed at the top of you notebook should make it so that any function returning a multiline string, i.e., having \n in there, will display the result on multiple lines:
from IPython.core.formatters import BaseFormatter
from IPython.display import display, HTML

class MultilineStringFormatter(BaseFormatter):
    def __call__(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, str) and '\n' in obj:
            return f'<pre>{obj}</pre>'
        return None

# Register the custom formatter
ip = get_ipython()
ip.display_formatter.formatters['text/html'].for_type(str, MultilineStringFormatter())

Related resources:

the answer to 'How to override ipython displayhook?' is insightful to some of the inner workings I ended up using.
this excellent answer that taps in to how to integrate output into IPython handling was what you could have used if you had just one or two functions like this because you could control how the output is represented. (Like what I suggested here for adding repr_html() method to a dataframe handling class.) However, for doing that with each it wouldn't have been better than just using print() everywhere. So tapping into the global displayhook to do this for all is better.

